# Multiple expression in ng-show - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Why cannot i have multiple expression in ng-show?

Im using this line

```
<tr ng-show="!container.isfavorite" ng-repeat="container in account">
```

when i try this it wont work:

```
<tr ng-show="!container.isfavorite || !container.isHidden" ng-repeat="container in account">
```

There is no error message just that the `ng-repeat` then wont work properly by showing both `container.isfavorite` and `container.isHidden` (like they are ignored)

How can i have multiple impressions inside ng-show?

Update:
**This is my code for isfavorite:**

```
<md-button ng-class="{yellow : container.isfavorite}"
               ng-click="container.isfavorite =!container.isfavorite; AddFavorite(container.isfavorite,container.containerId)"
               class="md-icon-button md-accent md-warn" aria-label="Favorite">
<ng-md-icon icon="favorite" ng-init="container.isfavorite = false;"></ng-md-icon>
</md-button>
```

**This is my code for isHidden:**

```
<md-button ng-class="{zebbi : container.isHidden}"
           ng-click="container.isHidden =!container.isHidden; Hidecontainer(container.isHidden, container.containerId);"
           class="md-icon-button md-accent md-warn" aria-label="Hide">
<ng-md-icon ng-if="!container.isHidden" icon="remove_red_eye"></ng-md-icon>
<ng-md-icon ng-if="container.isHidden" icon="panorama_fisheye"></ng-md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your expression.  Are you sure the logic is correct?  You have a lot of negation going on there.  Why not just `ng-hide="container.isfavorite && container.isHidden"`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your statement. I've similar examples working fine for me. Something is probably up with your conditional values.

Comment: Or possibly a typo of some sort.  The capitalization of your properties is inconsistent `favorite` vs `Hidden`.

Comment: ng-hide="container.isfavorite && container.isHidden" did not work and no there is no Typo. Ill post in question the button of isfavorite and isHidden

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a limitation. You can use any number of expression in ng-show.

There is no any syntax errors on your code but seem like there should be logical error that's why your code is not working as expected.

Re-check expressions in  ng-show directive.